# Find out how many hardware performance counters a CPU has

Tags: linux, x86-64, intel, perf, papi

On an Intel or AMD x86-64 system running Linux, where/how can I find out the number of hardware performance counters that my CPU has?

I would like to use the Linux `perf` tool to gather hardware performance counter data while executing some applications. The perf wiki's [tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) says that if I specify (using the `-e` flag to `perf stat` or `perf record`) more hardware events than there are performance counters in my CPU, then these events will be multiplexed over the counters during the execution, allowing them to all be tracked during a single `perf` command, but possibly reducing accuracy because not all counters are active all the time. (Note that I am concerned with hardware events here, such as for cache and TLB behavior - I know that a large/unlimited number of kernel software tracepoints can be tracked without inaccuracy).

If I find out my processor model, is there an Intel/AMD website where I can find this information? Is there a simple command that I can run on the system to check the number of hardware counters? I've examined the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `x86info -a`, but couldn't find this information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding Intel processors, you can:

- look in this intel [documentation manual chapter 18](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.html), but it's not so easy to read.
- use the [`cpuid` instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) - This will require to write assembly code to correctly set parameters and get results.
- download and compile/install the [papi library](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) and run `papi_avail | more`. The result on my laptop is:

> PAPI Version             : 5.1.1.0
>
> Vendor string and code   : GenuineIntel (1)
>
> Model string and code    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (42)
>
> CPU Revision             : 7.000000
>
> CPUID Info               : Family: 6  Model: 42  Stepping: 7
>
> CPU Max Megahertz        : 2494
>
> CPU Min Megahertz        : 2494
>
> Hdw Threads per core     : 2
>
> Cores per Socket         : 2
>
> NUMA Nodes               : 1
>
> CPUs per Node            : 4
>
> Total CPUs               : 4
>
> Running in a VM          : no
>
> Number Hardware Counters : 11
>
> Max Multiplex Counters   : 64

Comment: To my understanding, the `Number Hardware Counters : 11` is the sum of `fixed counters` and `general-purpose` counters which in many architectures are 3 and 8. So the `Number of Hardware Counters` on what we see above is 11 **per core**. Right?